# Prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

So, i see some question: Determine prime elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}.$ I think that, $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ is a field  cause $5$ is prime. Then, is domain too. Thus, in a field we have that the only Ideals are ${0}$ and $\langle 1\rangle.$ But if we have integral domain, $p$ is prime element iff $\langle p\rangle$ is prime ideal.. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ dont have prime elements?

Comment: If I recall correctly, a prime element must be first of all nonzero and not a unit , so your reasoning is correct.

Comment: Thanks bro ^_^.

Comment: Glad to be of help. By the way, that is the first time I have been called "bro" by anyone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An element $p$ in a commutative ring is prime iff the ideal generated by $p$ is a non-zero prime ideal.

Thus as $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field its only ideals are $(0),(1)$, neither of which are non-zero prime ideals.

Thus the ring has no prime elements.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing $\mathbb{Z}_5$ with $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, where one is the field with 5 elements and the other is the ring of 5-adic integers, which clearly has prime elements and prime ideals.